# HP Smart Array P420i Array Management in ESXi 5.5

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have a HP DL380p Gen8 server with ESXi 5.5 running on it and HP Smart Array P420i. I've installed 4 new hard disks on it and want to put them in a RAID 6 array (Although RAID 10 would be OK too).

Hoping to run hpacucli, this is what I thought would work:
http://www.virtualtothecore.com/en/manage-an-hp-smart-array-directly-from-vmware-esxi/

But now, when I run hpacucli via esxcli, I get this error:

```
Error: No controllers detected.
```

Is there anything I forgot? Or any advice how to find the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The tool you should be using *today* is `hpssacli`. The older `hpacucli` utility doesn't work on current-generation ProLiant servers.

In case you don't have `hpssacli`, the support download bundle [for your server is here](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=5177958&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=swEnvOID%253D4166%257CswLang%253D%257Caction%253DlistDriver&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) (if you're not already using the HP ESXi build).

*Also, RAID6 for 4 disks doesn't make sense. Do RAID 1+0*

---

```
~ # /opt/hp/hpacucli/bin/hpacucli
HP Array Configuration Utility CLI 9.40.12.0
Detecting Controllers...Done.
Type "help" for a list of supported commands.
Type "exit" to close the console.

=> ctrl all show config

Error: No controllers detected. 

=>
```

*versus*

```
~ # /opt/hp/hpssacli/bin/hpssacli
HP Smart Storage Administrator CLI 1.50.4.0
Detecting Controllers...Done.
Type "help" for a list of supported commands.
Type "exit" to close the console.

=> ctrl all show config

Smart Array P420i in Slot 0 (Embedded)    (sn: 001438023DA3BF0)


   SEP (Vendor ID PMCSIERA, Model SRCv8x6G) 380 (WWID: 5001438023DA3BFF)

=>
```

Comment: Thanks! Really saved me lots of time!
But I didn't get your point about RAID6. What is the disadvantage?
Do you mean that it's a waste of capacity and I need more disks in a RAID6 array?

Comment: @MohammadrezaMontazeriShatoori There's a performance penalty. RAID 1+0 with 4 disks will perform better.

Comment: @MohammadrezaMontazeriShatoori RAID6 requires two parity disks, which leaves you with the same usable storage as RAID 1+0 does. RAID1+0 performs a _lot_ better.

Comment: And if `hpssacli` shows `no controllers detected`, run `modprobe sg` and try again, as per support.hp.com/id-en/document/c04647234 . This is a problem today on RHEL/Centos 7.1.

Comment: I would say that RAID 6 does "make sense" for four disks, and unlike RAID 1+0 it does allow any two drives to fail without losing integrity.  The obvious trade off is the speed, but I would reserve a term like "doesn't make sense" for logical impossibilities like RAID 10 on three disks, or RAID 6 on two disks.